is it possible to change the click function of the ellipsis in kendo ui kendo-scheduler-month-view
is it possible to change the click function of the ellipsis in kendo ui kendo-scheduler-month-view?
i need to change the click function of the ellipsis on the shown screenshot below:

<kendo-scheduler
    [resources]="[]"
    [kendoSchedulerBinding]="events"
    [(selectedViewIndex)]="schedulerView"
    [slotClass]="getSlotClass"
    [selectedDate]="selectedDate"
    [slotDivisions]="1"
    [selectable]="true"
    [isSlotSelected]="isSlotSelected"
    (slotDragStart)="onSlotDragStart($event)"
    (slotDrag)="onSlotDrag($event)">

    <kendo-scheduler-month-view [eventHeight]="18" [eventClass]="getEventClass">
      <ng-template kendoSchedulerEventTemplate let-event="event" let-resources="resources">
        <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="eventTemplate; context: { $implicit: event.dataItem }"></ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-scheduler-month-view>

</kendo-scheduler>

